# PHP Login Page with SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have created a login page with php mysql. It is working fine but I do not understand a part of the code. I understand php session but cannot figure out what `$obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r)` means:

```
$r = mysql_query($q); 
if ( $obj = @mysql_fetch_object($r) )
{
    $_SESSION["valid_localid"] = $obj->id;
    $_SESSION["valid_localuser"] = $_POST["username"];
    $_SESSION["valid_localtime"] = time();

    Header("Location: homepage.php");
}
else
{
    die("Sorry, could not log you in. Wrong login information.");
}
```

Comment: You mean particularly the `@` operator, right?

Comment: You created a page and yet have no idea what it does? That's awkward. Anyway, have you already read the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object) for `mysql_fetch_object`?

Comment: yes. and why that is applied here

Comment: The @ operator is to ignore warnings and errors. This is bad! Also when reading info about `mysql_*` functions you have noticed the warnings? Don't use `mysql_*`

Comment: you haven't actually read the manual, a _deprecated_ red block should appear and you'd know you shouldn't use mysql_* functions.

Comment: what I mean is, I created a login page without using this. and it worked fine. '$num_results = mysql_num_rows($q);
  
  if($num_results > 0)
  {
   $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"];
   
   Header("Location: aboutuser.php");
  }'

Comment: is anything wrong in the way I did it?

Comment: @user1629766 Like we tell you multiple times: your whole code is wrong. Stop using `mysql_*` functions! Stop using the `@` operator to ignore warnings and errors. Getting a result does NOT mean your code works fine...

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_object is a PHP function and it will fetch a result row as an object. And the @ operator simply means that any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.
You can get more help in http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Comment: thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I think I didn't ask the right question. I created this login page in two ways :- the code for the first one is above. The second way is the following :- '$num_results = mysql_num_rows($q);
  
  if($num_results > 0)
  {
   $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $_POST["username"];
   
   Header("Location: aboutuser.php");
  }'

Comment: I hope you find the difference. It worked fine in both cases. I want to know is anything wrong in the second approach?

Comment: @user1629766 the point is that the code works  doesn't mean is alright.

Comment: @luchosrock - exactly. can u tell me how to make it alright ?

Comment: @user1629766 the way Ultimate explained in his answer. (read the manual)

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_fetch_object()` function returns a row from a recordset as an object and you are using `@mysql_fetch_object()` which supresses error messages and warnings.

For more information about `mysql_fetch_object()` read manual :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php